# Laravel: How to use the same post form for multiple sections

Tags: laravel

I want to build something like facebook and I have a form where the user can post content but I want to use the same form on different sections, for example: groups, pages, profile.
I have PostController that is a resource that receives the post requests but I need a way to differentiate between sections in order to store the data with the correct section_type and section_id.

```
// Post Model Post.php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['content', 'user_id'];

    public function section()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }

    public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
    }
}
```

The User.php Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Post::class, 'section');
    }
}
```

and this is the PostController and store() function where I have only one situation at this moment where a post is stored in section_type App\User, but I need a way to store it in App\Group or App\Page also.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate(request(),
            [
                'content' => 'required|min:5',
            ]);

        $user = User::find(Auth::id());

        $user->posts()->create([
            'content' => $request->content,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ]);

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

What do I need to do in PostController.php? 
I thought maybe I could use a post request with parameters in the form, like this for posting in groups

```
<form method="post" action="/?group=1">
```

or this for posts in pages

```
<form method="post" action="/?page=1">
```

And after that use $request->query() to get the section and id. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: @you can create sepeate blade template and include it in between form tag or else you can add <form method="post" action="> action based on condtional statement

Comment: I would look at using a hidden field if you _really_ have to use an ambiguous form, where you will be able to get the input in the controller. Normally I would suggest a different form for each different purpose.